# Connect mamp6 to mysql

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm having problems with mamp 6 on mac. Always giving me an error in every connection to BD. does anyone have the solution?

Error:"Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw you will find everything in this link which you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)